# AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'SimpleQueue'

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

I follow typing the code from https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#async-ios-roots-in-generators to practice crawling with aiohttp.

Especially when I started to code section '**A Full Program: Asynchronous Requests**', I encountered an error.

Here is my code.

```
async def fetch_html(url: str, session: ClientSession, **kwargs) -> str:
    resp = await session.request(method='GET', url=url, **kwargs)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    html = await resp.text()
    return html

async def bulk_crawl_and_write(file: IO, urls: set, **kwargs) -> None:
    urls = [
        'https://regex101.com/'
    ]
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(fetch_html(url=url, session=session, **kwargs))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(bulk_crawl_and_write(file=None, urls=None))
```

And the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "areq2.py", line 108, in <module>
    asyncio.run(bulk_crawl_and_write(file=outpath, urls=urls))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "areq2.py", line 92, in bulk_crawl_and_write
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "areq2.py", line 79, in write_one
    async with aiofiles.open(file, "a") as f:
  File "/Users/jun/Project/.venv_exp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiofiles/base.py", line 78, in __aenter__
    self._obj = yield from self._coro
  File "/Users/jun/Project/.venv_exp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiofiles/threadpool/__init__.py", line 35, in _open
    f = yield from loop.run_in_executor(executor, cb)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 749, in run_in_executor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._work_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'SimpleQueue'
```

I copy & pasted the whole code from the provided link to check if the rest codes are essential to run normal, but it returns the same error.

I also checked my python version and it is 3.7.3

Comment: by any chance do you have another file named `queue.py`?

Comment: I actually do. what a rookie mistake. Thanks. @buran

Answer (score 2):

SimpleQueue is new in Python 3.7 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.SimpleQueue)

Check your Python version:
`python --version`

Answer (score 1):

check it out whether if the problem happened because of file name
I would appreciate if you found out the solution share it here, some people like me maybe encounter with same issue